# Python 2.4 - Installing Modules Syntax Error

Tags: python

I'm currently teaching myself Python and am working my way through `automatetheboringstuff.com`.  I'm having trouble installing third party modules in Python 2.4 (this is the newest version I have available to me at work).  For instance, when I try to install the `requests` module so I can work with web pages, I get an `invalid syntax` error.  Here's the procedure I'm using:

1. Open command line and cd to the folder where the setup.py file for the module is
2. Type into the command line: setup.py install

Then I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\PyRequestsModule\setup.py", line 52
   with open('requests/_init__py', 'r') as fd:
           ^
syntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I get a similar error every time I try to install a module.  Is the issue that I'm running Python 2.4 or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `with` was added in Python 2.5.

Comment: Yes the problem is that you are running a 13-year-old version of Python, which unsurprisingly is not compatible with modern libraries.

Comment: Your teaching yourself Python *at work*?

Answer (score 0):

Please **do not learn Python 2**, if you do not have to use this version for legacy reasons. Its support will end 2020 and most libraries are available for Python 3 too. Some even only for Python 3.

If you can't *install* a newer version, you can try to use a [portable one](https://winpython.github.io/).